# Extract all values of a key from a JSON array and add them to List

Tags: java

I am trying to Extract all values of a key from a JSON array and add them to List .

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "null", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        java.util.List FResult = null;

        String str = "[{\"email_address\":\"Test@test.com\",\"user_id\":1001,\"user_name\":\"Ben\",\"employee_id\":1001},{\"email_address\":\"Test@test.com\",\"user_id\":1001,\"user_name\":\"Ben\",\"employee_id\":1001}]";
        JSONArray objects = new JSONArray(str);

        for(int i=0;i<objects.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = objects.getJSONObject(i);

            FResult.add(jsonObject.getInt("user_id"));
```

I am trying to extract all values of user_id and add them to a List.

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is a Q&A site; it requires you to ask a question.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that you are calling a method from a null object so it throws a nullpointerexception.

```
List<int> FResult = new ArrayList<>();
```

I hope it will solve your issue.

Regards

Comment: Please do not add comments unrelated to the solution in your answer. Keep in mind that this answer is not just for the OP but also for future readers.

Comment: Also, your code has a compile-time error. Please check your solution before posting an answer. And the list is already declared, just not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.List FResult = null;
```

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because your `List` is `null`. You need to initialize your `List`:

```
java.util.List<Integer> FResult = new ArrayList<>();
```